# Trying to simulate 2 dice to know the percentage of same outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dice

So, i think they is a logical  error somewhere in the code.
The output keeps running 0% no matter any number i insert in the output terminal

```
#dice - count doubles in user - defined number of rounds.. repeated 
import random

#simulate rolling a six sided die and return its value. 
def rollOneDie():
    #generate random numbers from 1 to 6
    thisFace = random.randrange(1,7)
    return thisFace



while True:
    nDoubles = 0
    maxRounds = input(
        "how many rounds do you want to roll?(or ENTER to quit):")
    if maxRounds == '':
        break
    try:
        maxRounds = int(maxRounds)
    except:
        print("please an integer number")
        continue

    for roundNumbers in range(0, maxRounds):
        die1 = rollOneDie()
        die2 = rollOneDie()

    if die1 == die2:
        nDoubles = nDoubles + 1

    percent = (nDoubles * 100.0) / maxRounds
    print('out of ', maxRounds,  'you rolled',
      nDoubles, 'doubles or ', percent, '%')
print('ok byeee')
```

Comment: you want `random.randint(1,7)`

Comment: It's is because you always calculate nDoubles. Most of the times is 0

Comment: You want to calculate the probability of getting the same number on a dice with every iteration

Comment: @Sujay but the value of nDoubles = 0

Comment: @Sujay   i have tried both solutions but i still dont have the intented output in the terminal

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: @Sujay got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it prints 0% is that the if statement which checks if the dice are the same is outside the for loop that "rolls" the dice, so the nDoubles increases by 1 only if the dice are the same the last time you "roll" them.

The correct way is:

```
for roundNumbers in range(0, maxRounds):
    die1 = rollOneDie()
    die2 = rollOneDie()

    if die1 == die2:
        nDoubles = nDoubles + 1
```

Also, you can write:

```
nDoubles += 1
```

instead of

```
nDoubles = nDoubles + 1
```